# web2py unit testing on GAE

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, web2py

How can I test web2py units that are intended to be run on GAE?

I learned to run tests using this method:
python web2py.py -S api -M -R applications/api/tests/test.py

But how do I run tests with dev_appserver.py & web2py.py?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are testing requests, all you need to to do run unit tests is to have the Google App Engine SDK in your Python path.

I found it a little bit annoying so I built [testable-appengine](https://github.com/rbanffy/testable_appengine) to automate the setup process (and add a couple nice things to the virtualenv it builds). It also has some interesting examples of how you can install third-party libraries for deployment alongside the application. I'd love to see how it works with Web2Py.